# How to open a web socket after button has been pressed in vuejs?

Tags: websocket, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Usually, the web socket is started from the `main.js`. Now, I use the following:

```
import VueNativeSock from 'vue-native-websocket'
vue.use(VueNativeSock, 'ws://localhost:4113', { format: 'json' });
```

In this case, the web socket is started *when I load the page*.

I wonder if it would be possible to open the web socket after a button has been pressed rather than when a page has been loaded. For instance, in `HelloWorld.js` the generic VueJS component where I have added the following:

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" @click="submit" v-model="buttonInput">Submit</md-button>
```

I would like to have something like the following but it does not work.

```
methods: {
    submit: function(val){
      this.use(VueNativeSock, 'ws://localhost:4113', { format: 'json' });
      this.$socket.sendObj({website: this.urlInput});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is currently impossible to to what you need, because [**`VueNativeSock` is a plugin**](https://github.com/nathantsoi/vue-native-websocket/blob/f30c155298560cd93e0fdc1e58c3a1406703d6bf/src/Main.js#L6).

An Vue Plugins [can only be used through the global `Vue.use()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Using-a-Plugin):

> #### Using a Plugin
>
> Use plugins by calling the `Vue.use()` global method:
>
> `` js // calls `MyPlugin.install(Vue)` Vue.use(MyPlugin) ``
>
> You can optionally pass in some options:
>
> `js Vue.use(MyPlugin, { someOption: true })`

There have been [some discussions about allowing locally](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/63), mostly for testing purposes, so that possibility only exist in `vue-test-utils` at the moment.

**Note:** `VueNativeSock` also currently doesn't provide another way (say a method) to start the webSocket. It [is opened](https://github.com/nathantsoi/vue-native-websocket/blob/f30c155298560cd93e0fdc1e58c3a1406703d6bf/src/Observer.js#L23) upon [Plugin Install method](https://github.com/nathantsoi/vue-native-websocket/blob/f30c155298560cd93e0fdc1e58c3a1406703d6bf/src/Main.js#L9) and the install happens the moment you do `Vue.use()`.

## Fix

Use `Vue.use(VueNativeSock, 'ws://localhost:4113', { format: 'json' });` (instead of `this.use(...)`.

But mind the time the socket will take to open. So your `this.$socket.sendObj`  may not be readily available **right after** the `Vue.use()` call. Here's a demo that waits for the WebSocket connection to open before sending the message:

```js
 /* workaround because we are not using via <script> and not via require()/import */
VueNativeSock = VueNativeSock.default;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    createAndSend() {
      Vue.use(VueNativeSock, 'wss://echo.websocket.org/', { format: 'json' });
      
      this.$socket.onopen = () => {
        console.log('WebSocket opened');
        
        // registering listeners
        this.$socket.onmessage = (data) => console.log('Received data:', data.data);
        
        // sending data
        console.log('Sending data');
        this.$socket.sendObj({awesome: 'data'});
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/nathantsoi/vue-native-websocket/master/dist/build.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h3>Check the console</h3>
  <button @click="createAndSend">Create WebSocket and Send Message</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, I just added a runnable demo of how to wait until the connection is opened before sending the message. Hope it helps. Cheers.